# Hiding data label on data bar if 0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got a Data Bar and I'm only showing the percentage label on the bottom area. But if that portion is 0 I do not want to show a label at all.

If I use:

```
=IIf(sum(count(Fields!SEStatusID.Value = 2 And Fields!MathStatusID.Value=2)) > 0, true, false)
```

Then I get all data labels shown.

If I use:

```
=IIf(count(Fields!SEStatusID.Value = 2 And Fields!MathStatusID.Value=2) > 0, true, false)
```

Then I get all data labels shown.

How do I not show a data label if there are no Fields!SEStatusID.Value = 2 AND no Fields!MathStatusID.Value=2?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an inner IIF statement.

```
=IIF(Sum(IIF(Fields!SEStatusID.Value = 2 And Fields!MathStatusID.Value = 2, 1,0))=0,False,True)
```